# Inexact ADMM without over-relaxation

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Let f$,g$ be proper closed convex functions, $u=(y,z)$, and the problem:
$$ \begin{equation} \begin{split}
\min_{x,u} \ &f(x) + g(u) \\
\text{s.t. } & Ax + Bu = c
\end{split} \end{equation}
$$

We may use the ADMM framework, so that iteration $k$ consists in:
$$ \begin{equation} \begin{split}
x_{k+1} &= \arg\min_{x} L_p(x,u_k,\lambda_k) \\
u_{k+1} &= \arg\min_{u} L_p(x_{k+1},u,\lambda_k) \\
\lambda_{k+1} &= \lambda_k + p ( Ax_{k+1} + Bu_{k+1} - c )
\end{split} \end{equation}
$$
where  $ L_p(x,u,\lambda) = f(x) + g(u) + \langle \lambda, Ax + Bu - c \rangle + \frac{p}{2} \| Ax + Bu - c \|_2^2 $ is the Augmented Lagrangian associated to the problem.

However, assume that the subproblem for $u$ is difficult to solve.  Let us split the $u$-update with a pass of Block-Coordinate Descent (BCD) in $y,z$ to get easy to solve subproblems:
$$ \begin{equation} \begin{split}
x_{k+1} &= \arg\min_{x} L_p(x,y_k,z_k,\lambda_k) \\
y_{k+1} &= \arg\min_{y} L_p(x_{k+1},y,z_k,\lambda_k) \\
z_{k+1} &= \arg\min_{z} L_p(x_{k+1},y_{k+1},z,\lambda_k) \\
\lambda_{k+1} &= \lambda_k + p ( Ax_{k+1} + Bu_{k+1} - c )
\end{split} \end{equation}
$$

We separated the $u$-update, which should be done exactly. This makes us leave the standard 2-block ADMM.

Also assume the function $g(y,z) \neq g_1 (y) + g_2(z)$ i.e. not separable in the two variables so that the analysis in terms of a 3 block ADMM (see [The Direct Extension of ADMM for Multi-block Convex Minimization Problems is Not Necessarily Convergent](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eyyye/ADMM-final.pdf)) is not possible.

I've seen the [Generalized ADMM](https://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Eckstein_Bertsekas_D-R.pdf) (Theorem 8) which allows inexact updates, but it adds a relaxation term to the standard ADMM which I don't want.

I also see that repeated BCD passes would result in a more precise minimization over $u$ but it would be too heavy.

Comment: So what is your question? Do you want to see a convergence proof for Gauss-Seidel type multi-block ADMM?

Comment: @Kurban I would like to get pointers on the convergence of standard 2-block ADMM when one of the two variable is split via BCD/Gauss-Siedel